# Writing to java file with GUI won't write correctly

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, filewriter

So what I'm trying to do is write the `clientName, date, hour` to the fileWriter.txt document. I am writing into a `Random Access Memory File`. At the moment if I type the correct values it will output in the wrong format!

#### For Example:

`Client Name = "James", Date="1", Hour="1"`
For some reason this will output the following line - `00,00,          ,  null01,James     ,1         ,`
They are being writer to the file according to the `date` they enter.

Also, is there a way I can write to the file and then delete the GUI values so they can enter a new one?

#### Here Is My Code:

```
##Correct Imports Here
public class CreateRandomDataFile extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static JButton submit;
    private static JLabel output;
    private static JLabel bankDetails;
    private static JTextField txtClient = new JTextField("", 20);
    private static JTextField txtDate = new JTextField("",6);
    private static JTextField txtHour = new JTextField("",6);

    private static JLabel lblClient = new JLabel("Client");
    private static JLabel lblDate = new JLabel("Date");
    private static JLabel lblHour = new JLabel("Hour");


    private static Path file = Paths.get("fileWriter.txt");
    private static String s = "00,          ,  "
            + System.getProperty("line.seperator");
    private static FileChannel fc = null;
    private static int RECSIZE = s.length();


    private String client = "";
    private int date;
    private int hour;

    public CreateRandomDataFile(){
        super("Create Data File");
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



        output = new JLabel();
        submit = new JButton("Submit");

        bankDetails = new JLabel();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        add(lblClient);
        add(txtClient);
        txtClient.addActionListener(this);

        add(lblDate);
        add(txtDate);
        txtDate.addActionListener(this);

        add(lblHour);
        add(txtHour);
        txtHour.addActionListener(this);


        add(submit);
        submit.addActionListener(this);

        add(output);


    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object source = e.getSource();
        int counter = 0;
        if(source == submit){
            client = txtClient.getText();
            //int newDate = Integer.parseInt(txtDate.getText());
            date = Integer.parseInt(txtDate.getText());
            hour = Integer.parseInt(txtHour.getText());


            try{
                 fc = (FileChannel)Files.newByteChannel(file, READ, WRITE);
//                OutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file, CREATE));
//                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outStream)); 

                String as=date + "";
                for(int i=as.length();i<2;i++){
                    //s="";
                    //s+="0";
                    s+="0" + date;
                }
                s+=","+client;
                for(int i=client.length();i<10;i++){
                    s+=" ";
                }
                s+= "," + hour;
                String hourLen = hour + "";
                for(int i=hourLen.length();i<2;i++){
                    s += " ";
                }

                byte[] data = s.getBytes();
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
                fc.position(date * RECSIZE);
                fc.write(buffer);


//                writer.write(s, 0, s.length());
//                writer.newLine();
                fc.close();
            }
            catch(Exception eStream){
                System.out.println("Incorrect");
            }
        }
    }
     public static void main(String[] args){
        CreateRandomDataFile writer = new CreateRandomDataFile();
        writer.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

#### Here is my file that creates a null file

```
public class createRandomNullFile {
     public static void main(String[] args){
        //Limit of student records allowed
        final int NO_STUDENTS = 100;

        //Create the file
        Path file = Paths.get("fileWriter.txt");

        //Default value for every record in the Random Access file (Students.txt)
        String s = "00,          ,  " 
                + System.getProperty("line.separator"); // After each record goto new line


        //Array - Get contents of string and add to data array
        byte[] data = s.getBytes();

        try{
         OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(
                 Files.newOutputStream(file, CREATE));
         BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));
        for(int i=0;i< NO_STUDENTS;i++){
            bw.write(s, 0, s.length());

        }
        bw.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Empty file created");

        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println("Error connecting or writing to file");
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `System.getProperty("line.seperator")` use `System.lineSeparator()`.

Comment: @user1803551 - This doesn't seem to fix it. It will instead add a null value.

Comment: I didn't post this as an answer, it's a comment with an improvement.

Comment: Also, you are asking two separate questions which seem unrelated. You should ask them in different questions. Although not clear, it seems like your second code is related to your first question and the first code is related to the second.

Answer (score 0):

The String that you are writing to the file is initialised at the top of the class

```
private static String s = "00,          ,  "
        + System.getProperty("line.seperator");
```

This is where the "00,00,          ,  null" portion of the string is coming from (the null is due to the incorrect property name; it should be line.separator), you should either clear this string before using it or create a new one.

To clear the GUI, clear the textfields by putting the following inside the actionPerformed method after writing to the file

```
txtClient.setText("");
txtDate.setText("");
txtHour.setText("");
```

Comment: It's not actually replacing the line - It's putting the values in after the already made line ("00,            ,  " then it adds the user enter data after this). How would I fix this??

Comment: You've put "line.seperator" when it should be "line.separator", changing that should be enough

Answer (score 0):

I's not clear how you want to get an output other than `"00,          ,  "` since this is the only string you write. Here is your code slightly modified:

```
public class createRandomNullFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int NO_STUDENTS = 10;
        Path file = Paths.get("fileWriter.txt");
        String s = "00,          ,  " + System.lineSeparator();

        try {
            OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));
            for (int i = 0; i < NO_STUDENTS; i++) {
                bw.write(s, 0, s.length());
            }
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error connecting or writing to file");
        }
    }
}
```

which creates a text file with the content:

```
00,          ,  
00,          ,  
00,          ,  
00,          ,  
00,          ,  
00,          ,  
00,          ,  
00,          ,  
00,          ,  
00,          ,
```